# Prove operator is isometry

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},m,T)$ be a probability preserving transformation.

Prove that the operator $U:f\mapsto f\circ T$ satisfies
$$
\|Uf\|_{p}=\|f\|_{p}
$$
for every $1\le p<\infty$.

My idea:
$$
\|Uf\|^p_p=\int\limits_X|f\circ T|^p\mathrm{d}m=\int\limits_X |f|^p\mathrm{d}T^*m=\int\limits_X |f|^p\mathrm{d}m
$$

where in the last equality I used the fact that the measure $m$ is invariant.

However I can't justify the second passage in the equality above.
Above, $T^*$ is the push-forward measure: $T^*(A):=m(T^{-1}A)$.

Comment: Try proving it first for characteristic functions of sets and then for step functions.... Use density.

Comment: So the the only task is to show that property for simple functions. Then we know that simple functions are dense in $L^p$, hence I conclude. I can, in particular, extend the result to the case $p=\infty$, since what has been said above holds for the latter case as well.

Comment: My problem, however, is still to show that the thesis holds for simple functions...

Answer (score 1):

If $1_A$ is the characteristic function of some set, then 
$$1_A \circ T=1_{T^{-1}(A)}$$

Therefore, if $f =\sum a_i 1_{A_i}$ you have
$$f \circ T = \sum a_i ( 1_{A_i} \circ T)=  \sum a_i 1_{T^{-1}(A_i)} $$

Thus
$$\int\limits_X|f\circ T|^p\mathrm{d}m=\int\limits_X|\sum a_i 1_{T^{-1}(A_i)}|^p\mathrm{d}m=\int\limits_X|\sum a_i 1_{A_i}|^p\mathrm{d} T^* m$$

Comment: Sorry for the insistence. How do you explain the last inequality?

Comment: @avati91 Look at it backwards. What is the definition of $T^*(A)$?  What does $$\int\limits_X|\sum a_i 1_{A_i}|^p\mathrm{d} T^* m$$ mean then?

Comment: $\int\limits_X |\sum a_i 1_{A_i}|^p\circ T dm$

Comment: @avati91 Which is exactly the last equality in the solution ;)

Comment: why I can't apply the same equality with $f\in L^p$?